# Extract parameters and result contents from website

Tags: web, screen-scraping

I have a website where I can input a list of strings and it'll display the results of each in the same format (basically a table).

What I want to do is to be able to save the results as well as their corresponding parameters (the input string that I searched) and output them into a file to analyze later. So basically capture my input and the output it returns. It's kind of like, if I search "stack" on google, I want my output file to be "stack" and all the displayed results from the search.

I've done some research on web and screen scraping, but I can't find anything that fits my needs. I looked into the `curl` function in php, but it looks like it can only get the contents of a specific URL, which I don't have since I'll be repeating the searches frequently.

I also looked into the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) and [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/features.htm#export), but they don't seem to be able to extract contents this dynamically.

I was wondering if there are any ideas or tips that I could use. I was thinking maybe a plugin or application that I could write that captures the parameters of my request (input strings) and the results sent from the server, but I'm not really sure how to do this, any tips? Or maybe there's an existing one that I wasn't able to find?

Thanks in advance!